# Docker, entrypoint strange behavior

Tags: docker

I have the following Docker File (from ubuntu image):

```
...

WORKDIR ${DJANGO_BASE_DIR} //--> /opt/django

COPY --chown=${USERNAME}:${USERNAME} /deployment/entrypoint.sh ${DJANGO_BASE_DIR}

USER ${USERNAME}

RUN echo ${DJANGO_BASE_DIR} //--> /opt/django

CMD ["bash","entrypoint.sh"] // I also tried ENTRYPOINT
```

My entrypoint is the following:

```
...
echo "Waiting for postgres..."

while ! nc -z $DB_HOST $DB_PORT; do
  sleep 0.1
done
cd
echo "PostgreSQL started"
echo $DJANGO_DEBUG
echo $(pwd) // display /home/django
....
```

I don't understand why my entrypoint is running on `/home/django` directory; I expect it to run on the `WORKDIR`, which is `/opt/django`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cd` command in your entrypoint script sets the working directory to the current user's home directory. Remove that and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to deal with this for an hour, and this "cd" sneaked into my code. Thank you again.